# A collapsed suspension bridge

Tags: situation, mystery

I used to cross a suspension bridge to go to the other side of the road, there used to sit the local market and I used to buy grocery from them. The bridge was well-built and strong, but suspended. One day, I crossed the same suspension bridge at **10 PM** to go to the local market, buy some fruits and vegetables, and then returned home. After coming home I turned on the TV and opened the news. In the news I saw them say that a suspension bridge collapsed at some point of time between **10:15** to **11 PM** and many dead bodies were found below the bridge on the ground and are yet to be identified. I saw that the same bridge collapsed which I crossed before! I thought, "Phew! , if only I had crossed the bridge at that time, I would have lost my life."

After a minute, I realised that I was not watching TV.

What had happened?

**Edit**: I received a partial correct answer which states that :-

> I am dead. But can anyone say how did I die?

**Edit** :

> @Ak19's answer shows that I was dead. Along with @IgorSowinski's Answer, which states why I was dead. This completes the puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think,

> You are dead, but you didn't realize that. Your spirit returned home and was watching TV. The bodies were **unidentified earlier**, but after a minute you have seen your dead body in the news footage. So, literally you're not watching TV.

Edit:

> I think the locals sat under the bridge (may be on the platform) and had their shops there. You and the locals died as the bridge fell over you.

> [image]

Comment: Correct, I am dead. But why so?

Comment: @Anonymous We have 2 different bridges?

Comment: No? definitely not. You were right, but why am I dead?

Comment: I shall accept the question only if you figure out why I was dead

Comment: @Anonymous, yep! I know, thinking .... 

Comment: Not really actually.  Read the question again and think in real life what would have happened if that incident would have happened in real (also a suspension bridge is not strong enough like a metal one, who would the locals have their shops there? By the way your picture make no sense, you should probably think that in those days there were no metal roads, and under the bridge is a bottomless pit)

Comment: I think what the OP wants you to say is that rot13(Nsgre lbhe reenaq lbh jbhyq arrq gb pebff n FRPBAQ gvzr gb trg onpx ubzr. Vg jnf ba guvf FRPBAQ gevc gung gur oevqtr pbyyncfrq naq lbh qvrq.)

Comment: @Stiv Thanks! But this line *"Phew! , if only ...."* is slightly puzzling....

Answer (score 3):

> The bridge collapsed when you were in the store. As it was nighttime, you've not noticed the missing bridge and tumbled to your death as you've attempted to take a step on it during your return home.

> It is also possible that the bridge simply collapsed when you were returning — not necessarily when you were at the store.

> The phrase "turned on the TV and opened the news" means that your death (as well as that of the others') was featured in a news programme as the first news item. Your corpse was indistinguishable from those of the victims of the collapse who were present on the bridge at the time it collapsed.

Comment: That's it, that explains why I was dead good job!

Answer (score 2):

You turned on the TV and opened the news

> Opening the news refers to reading a physical newspaper such as The Australian. You are primarily focussing on the newspaper which is more important than whatever happens to be on TV at the time. Perhaps someone is saying "just shut up and take my money" or some other ad that's even worse ;-)

Next,

> The newspaper has a picture of the suspension bridge you crossed at 10PM. The television mentions a **different bridge** had collapsed somewhere else.

Comment: Not what I expected, but that looks like a good idea to me. This sentence  "After a minute, I realised that I was not watching TV." has a different meaning

Answer (score 1):

> I did not see it leading to anything earlier, but if you are dead, it is probably because the bridge collapsed at 10.00 PM, quite possible since that is between 10.15 (AM) and 11.00 PM.

Comment: Yes but it didn't collapse at $10$ PM , why did I die then?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you died because you crossed the bridge at 11:00 p.m. when it collapsed, but you live in a different time zone and so your watch said it was 10:00 p.m. local time when you were crossing the bridge to get to the market. Keyword local market.

Answer (score 0):

On return he heard his name announced in TV among those confirmed dead.